# Is there a problem to use queue:work on a cron job?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, hosting, shared-hosting

I've deployed my laravel application on hostinger, and it has some queue jobs (as sending e-mails), I added a cron job with the artisan command "queue:work" and it's executing every 1 minute. I've done some research, and I've seen some people saying that it consumes a lot of RAM - especially because my cron job is setted up to execute the artisan command every 1 minute. 
If it's wrong, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into implementing `supervisor` to monitor your queue workers for you.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration

> To keep the queue:work process running permanently in the background, you should use a process monitor such as `Supervisor` to ensure that the queue worker does not stop running.

High RAM usage is generally associated with the `--daemon` flag.  However, this can be addressed by simply restarting the queue workers occasionally with `queue:restart`.  But when used properly, daemon workers are the most efficient because they do not "reboot" the application for each new job.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker

> Daemon queue workers do not "reboot" the framework before processing each job. Therefore, you should free any heavy resources after each job completes. For example, if you are doing image manipulation with the GD library, you should free the memory with `imagedestroy` when you are done.

If you cannot implement `supervisor` due to shared hosting restrictions, there are some workarounds such as using the `withoutOverlapping()` option to only start a new queue worker if the previous one has died.  I have used the following code in certain projects where `supervisor` was unavailable, and I have never had any issues.

```php
class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    // define your queues here in order of priority
    protected $queues = [
        'notifications',
        'default',
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // run the queue worker "without overlapping"
        // this will only start a new worker if the previous one has died
        $schedule->command($this->getQueueCommand())
            ->everyMinute()
            ->withoutOverlapping();

        // restart the queue worker periodically to prevent memory issues
        $schedule->command('queue:restart')
            ->hourly();
    }

    protected function getQueueCommand()
    {
        // build the queue command
        $params = implode(' ',[
            '--daemon',
            '--tries=3',
            '--sleep=3',
            '--queue='.implode(',',$this->queues),
        ]);

        return sprintf('queue:work %s', $params);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, using the schedule, I should use this command on my cron job? php /path/to/artisan schedule:run and configure to execute it every one minute?

Comment: You should use `/path/to/php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` and execute every minute `* * * * *` for your cron job.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, it worked! I think I can take a rest now, I was afraid of the High RAM usage!

Comment: Glad to help out!

Comment: Hey, I'm facing some problems. After one hour, the queue stop listening, so it won't send any emails after that. To work I used the "php artisan cache:clear" and "php artisan config:cache" commands.So must I add the schedule to run those commands every hour? I took a look at the cron output and there was this message: "No scheduled commands are ready to run."

Comment: What queue driver are you using?  Can you put your Kernel file into a gist (https://gist.github.com/) and provide the link in the comments?  Are you running in maintenance mode?

Comment: I'm using the database as the queue driver. https://gist.github.com/franciscotis/32f2c57109d9a0f17b84fd5e03020132. I'm not running it in maintenance mode.

Comment: I also use the database driver and I don't see any problems in your code.  This is certainly odd.  I've never had it stop running or need to clear the cache.  It is set to restart the queue periodically which you can adjust, but it should start processing again where it left off when the next cron job is called on the scheduler to restart the worker.  This should result in no more than 1 minute of queue downtime.  This short delay is a drawback of not using supervisor, but can be mitigated a bit by setting longer durations between the restarts as long as memory is okay.

Comment: Do you think the problem should be the queue:restart each hour? Do you think I should add the ->withoutOverlapping(); on this command?

Comment: There is no reason to use `withoutOverlapping()` because `queue:restart` is a short-lived process.  All it does is send a signal to stop any running queue workers (it's named poorly in my opinion since it doesn't actually restart anything).  The reason you must use `withoutOverlapping()` with `queue:work` is because that process continues to run until it dies.  That's why it's bad to keep calling `queue:work` by itself because you would end up with many, many queue worker processes running at the same time.  This would be bad for system resources.

Comment: Maybe try changing `->withoutOverlapping()` to `->withoutOverlapping(60)` [or maybe 61].  This should explicitly allow the worker command to run again after 1 hour.

Comment: Well, it kinda worked... So in the beginning the queue starts listening, but after 20 minutes or less, i don't know, it stops, so it wont send any emails or complete the jobs that are in the jobs table. But after one hour it starts working again (because of the queue:restart command). I changed the ->withoutOverlapping() to ->withoutOverlapping(60) and I made a little modification on the order of this command, as you can see here: https://gist.github.com/franciscotis/eed59801d5086ce781541de9495b8c17 ( I've read that the 'withoutOverlapping()' should appear before the 'everyMinute()')

Comment: Just an update: I changed the "withoutOverlapping(60)" to "withoutOverlapping (10)" and it worked.

Comment: after some times, how it worked this solution?