# How to call queue worker in background in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, background

I can't install Supervisor on my server, and I want more flexible way of running queue workers than CRON.
I tried calling artisan commands from SSH(Putty) - works, but I want to manage them from website,
so I tested PHP exec and Symfony Process class, I also downloaded Laravelcollective remote.
Every time no process was run, I didn't even get any error, just nothing.

```
Exec
public function call_worker(){
        $cmd = '(cd ' . dirname(getcwd()) . '/; php artisan queue:work)';
        exec($cmd);
    }
```

```
public function call_worker(){
        $cmd = '(cd ' . dirname(getcwd()) . '/; php artisan queue:work)';
        shell_exec($cmd);
    }
```

```
SSH in PHP
public function call_worker(){
        $cmd = '(cd ' . dirname(getcwd()) . '/; php artisan queue:work)';
        \SSH::run($cmd, function($line)
    {
        echo $line.PHP_EOL;
    });
```

```
public function call_worker(){
        $cmd = '(cd ' . dirname(getcwd()) . '/; php artisan queue:work) &';
        \SSH::run($cmd, function($line)
    {
        echo $line.PHP_EOL;
    });
```

```
Symfony Process class
public function call_worker(){
   $cmd = 'php artisan queue:work';
   $process = new Process($cmd);
   $process->setWorkingDirectory(dirname(getcwd()) . '/');
   $process->start();
}
```

From symfony Process I got once error 255 Uknown error.
'ls' command run like that worked each time.
Thanks in advance.

@edit Could it be issue becouse of "lsphp"?
@edit2 I manage to run worker in background using code bellow.
       I may encounter more problems, if so i will post them.

```
public function call_worker(){
        //echo shell_exec(dirname(getcwd()) . ' ls');
        //echo shell_exec('ls');
        $php = '/opt/alt/php73/usr/bin/php';
        $cmd = ' artisan queue:work';
        $process = new Process('/opt/alt/php73/usr/bin/php artisan queue:work &');
        $process->setWorkingDirectory(dirname(getcwd()) . '/');
        //$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('echo "$MESSAGE"');
        $process->start();
        $pid = $process->getPid();
        echo $pid;
        foreach ($process as $type => $data) {
    if ($process::OUT === $type) {
        echo "\nRead from stdout: ".$data;
    } else { // $process::ERR === $type
        echo "\nRead from stderr: ".$data;
    }
    }
        echo $process->getOutput();
    }
```

Comment: Is the issue that your hosting is too restrictive, and won't allow you to run a long running process such as the `php artisan queue:work` command? If so, the answer may be to find other hosting.

Comment: Actually in the past I made by mistake a loop, and i had to kill it manualy, and cron keeps calling schedule(workers) and doing some tasks that way, in early stages I was running worker without --once so it was filling up memory and running for very long time until i noticed that. I will ask them if is it like you say but I doubt it

Comment: It's possible to run the queue worker as a Laravel task scheduler command using the `withoutOverlapping()` method to prevent duplicate processes.  See this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471917/is-there-a-problem-to-use-queuework-on-a-cron-job/57472528#57472528  Just skip the parts about `supervisor`.